# What is the linkage connecting the body landing gear on the C-130?

Tags: landing-gear, c-130

I can't seem to find a diagram that includes this tube linking the front and rear body gear on each side. Is it structural, or hydraulic, or maybe something else entirely?

[image: KC-130 landing]

Image source: https://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/photo/001380858.html

Additional photo: https://www.airport-data.com/aircraft/photo/001454050.html

Answer (score 6):

It's structural. It's called a truck assembly or a bogey, on most aircraft. I used to work on C-130s, but it's been a long time and I don't recall the exact nomenclature that is used for that part in the C-130 world anymore. But it's just a structural part that keeps the front and rear wheels aligned with each other. Each main gear axle has a shock strut that retracts and extends on a jackscrew. Without it, there would be a lot more twisting force on the landing gear parts, which would lead to premature wear and potentional emergency situations that you definitely don't want to experience when taking off or landing. That part absorbs some of the twisting force and lightens the torsional load on the gear itself.